Keycloak, gateways and spring security in docker compose failed to login as Invalid credentials
I am using docker compose to start multiple services as below:

Keycloak
Spring cloud gateway
MySQL
Backend Service

I am ensure the github login was sucessfully. But the keycloak always return Invalid credentials.

Below was my docker compose files:
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /corporation-backend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "11001:11001"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/corp?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: corp_user
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: sdf21DFScv2$&*
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update
      SPRING_JPA_SHOW_SQL: true
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      TZ: Asia/Shanghai
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      keycloak:
        condition: service_healthy

  gateway:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /corporation-gateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "11000:11000"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker
      TZ: Asia/Shanghai
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      keycloak:
        condition: service_healthy

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:26.0.5
    environment:
      KC_DB: mysql
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/keycloak?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak_user
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: dfawadcxz23)ds
      KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_USERNAME: admin
      KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      TZ: Asia/Shanghai
    ports:
      - "12220:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./data/keycloak/import:/opt/keycloak/data/import
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      test: timeout 10s bash -c ':> /dev/tcp/localhost/8080'
      start_interval: 10s
    restart: always
    command: ["start-dev", "--import-realm", "--verbose"]

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - "13306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: sdcas12rds@1
      TZ: Asia/Shanghai
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/mysql/init/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - ./data/mysql/conf/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

And my gateways application-docker.yaml:
server:
  port: 11000

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: TRACE

spring:
  application:
    name: corporation-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay=
      routes:
        - id: corporation-backend
          uri: http://192.168.2.104:11001
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            authorization-uri: http://192.168.2.104:12220/realms/corp/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            issuer-uri: http://192.168.2.104:12220/realms/corp
            token-uri: http://192.168.2.104:12220/realms/corp/protocol/openid-connect/token
            user-info-uri: http://192.168.2.104:12220/corp/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: corp
            client-secret: qPIIMvydHtZCoVIQqNj7RuWsUGSis3iy
            redirect-uri: http://192.168.2.104:11000/login/oauth2/code/keycloak
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: openid


Security config as below:
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeExchange(auth -> auth.pathMatchers("/api/public").permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

}


Pom.xml
<properties>
    <java.version>21</java.version> <!-- Java版本 -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-boot.version>3.2.4</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.alibaba>2023.0.1.0</spring-cloud.alibaba>
  </properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Thanks,
Jojo Fuang
Also i tried using keycloak without docker, i deployed it in other PC ,and using on-perm networks, it was fine.
I compare the logs, it have some difference, after the login.

the docker one keycloak, will redirect to /login?failed pages.
the other PC keycloak, will return success.

If there anything i missed in the keycloak docker images setup ?
2024-12-29T16:23:03.495+08:00 DEBUG 24428 --- [corporation-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /login/oauth2/code/keycloak' doesn't match 'null /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
2024-12-29T16:23:03.495+08:00 DEBUG 24428 --- [corporation-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Checking match of request : '/login/oauth2/code/keycloak'; against '/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
2024-12-29T16:23:03.683+08:00 DEBUG 24428 --- [corporation-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-2] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : Saved SecurityContext 'SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [2cbbeccb-ada2-44bd-aba5-bf3d620b0a4c], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=drnun8cBLxGt4FtZyf-4zQ, sub=2cbbeccb-ada2-44bd-aba5-bf3d620b0a4c, resource_access={corp={roles=[corp_admin]}, account={roles=[corp_view-profile]}}, email_verified=false, iss=http://192.168.2.105:12220/realms/corp, typ=ID, preferred_username=jojofuang, given_name=Jojo, nonce=8Oi0rg2W7IJO_MbkYJD6VN8M8cyvw8hfjPbjV58jDlM, sid=1d6b60f8-1868-4500-b121-7653bb737416, aud=[corp], acr=1, realm_access={roles=[default-roles-corp, offline_access, uma_authorization]}, azp=corp, auth_time=2024-12-29T08:23:02Z, name=Jojo Fuang, exp=2024-12-29T08:28:02Z, family_name=Fuang, iat=2024-12-29T08:23:02Z, email=jojohzfan@outlook.com, jti=5cf6d904-4c70-45db-b5b6-95b6c4f196e2}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]' in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@2e754377'
2024-12-29T16:23:03.684+08:00 DEBUG 24428 --- [corporation-gateway] [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultServerRedirectStrategy  : Redirecting to '/api/token'

2024-12-29T16:24:38.281+08:00 DEBUG 31864 --- [corporation-gateway] [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultServerRedirectStrategy  : Redirecting to '/oauth2/authorization/keycloak'
2024-12-29T16:24:38.292+08:00 DEBUG 31864 --- [corporation-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-2] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Checking match of request : '/oauth2/authorization/keycloak'; against '/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
2024-12-29T16:24:38.295+08:00 DEBUG 31864 --- [corporation-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultServerRedirectStrategy  : Redirecting to 'http://192.168.2.104:12220/realms/corp/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=corp&scope=openid&state=JI65bs4_YmiVD9XVZUI93mSUZazydelW7rYooRJ3awo%3D&redirect_uri=http://192.168.2.104:11000/login/oauth2/code/keycloak&nonce=mzvrRdyxP-HQ9oJH7aYTHE4xKnO8poObBOTYDTN_4Ms'
2024-12-29T16:24:44.165+08:00 DEBUG 31864 --- [corporation-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-3] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /login/oauth2/code/keycloak' doesn't match 'null /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
2024-12-29T16:24:44.165+08:00 DEBUG 31864 --- [corporation-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-3] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /login/oauth2/code/keycloak' doesn't match 'null /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
2024-12-29T16:24:44.166+08:00 DEBUG 31864 --- [corporation-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-3] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Checking match of request : '/login/oauth2/code/keycloak'; against '/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
2024-12-29T16:24:44.167+08:00 DEBUG 31864 --- [corporation-gateway] [     parallel-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultServerRedirectStrategy  : Redirecting to '/login?error'

